tf2_sensor_msgs import error in ros2 humble
in this python code
import rclpy
from rclpy.node import Node
import numpy as np
from nav_msgs.msg import Path, Odometry
from sensor_msgs.msg import PointCloud2, PointField
from geometry_msgs.msg import PoseStamped
from visualization_msgs.msg import Marker, MarkerArray
from std_msgs.msg import Float32MultiArray
from rrt_python.corridor_finder import RRT_start
import sensor_msgs_py.point_cloud2 as pc2
from geometry_msgs.msg import Pose, PoseStamped
from std_msgs.msg import Header
import tf2_ros
import tf2_sensor_msgs``` got import error in tf2_sensor_msgs, but no error in tf2_ros. The tf2_sensor_msgs is not visible in the /opt/ros/humble/lib folder as shown in this screen shot [![enter image description here][1]][1]
But the package is being shown on typing ros2 pkg list command 
[![enter image description here][2]][2]

So far I've tried reinstalling the package multiple times and also upgrading ros, but nothing is working. Can someone kindly help

Hello, welcome to the comunity. Before I edit your post, I would like to inform you that the images you tried to share haven't been included succesfully. Please edit the question adding them if you think they are needed, and if not remove the comments.

welcome to Roboticks Stack Exchange! From the code it seems you are using ROS 2, right? Could you please attach the prompt of using the next command in the terminal?
ros2 pkg list

This command will show you all the packages you have sourced. For this reason, you will need to source ROS using source /opt/ros/{ROS_VERSION}/setup.bash before listing the packages. You should get a list similar to this:
ros2 pkg list | grep tf2
tf2
tf2_2d
tf2_bullet
tf2_eigen
tf2_eigen_kdl
tf2_geometry_msgs
tf2_kdl
tf2_msgs
tf2_py
tf2_ros
tf2_ros_py
tf2_sensor_msgs
tf2_tools

As you can see, you can use the grep command as well to just get which packages have tf2 in their names, which is the case for tf2_sensor_msgs
